# Coding an application so that it runs properly on windows 7...?

Tags: windows-7

I have a flash drive which has an application whose code is written VC++ 2008 , the application works fine in xp , but the problem arises when i plug in the drive to a windows 7 machine , it doesn't run properly. is there any way that i can make it compatible to windows by writing a code.

i dont want to set the compatibility tab in windows 7 to run the program..

i want to code it in the program , more like a patch.

Comment: In what way does it not "run properly"? For the most part, anything that runs on XP should run on Windows 7, but you'll have to much more specific.

Comment: By chance is the Win 7 a 64-bit version and the XP a 32-bit version?

Comment: @rajivpradeep: What is a "Memory Partition"? If you are referring to logical partitions, it's entirely likely your application needs to ask for administrative permissions once you move to Windows 7. Non-administrative applications are not allowed direct access to the physical disk media.

Comment: @rajivpradeep: Just because the code works correctly on Windows XP does not mean that the code is correct. If you rely on implementation details which were changed between the two operating systems, then bugs in the code will appear when you change platforms. Relying on non-documented behavior is a bug but will not appear unless you change your platform.

Comment: so, what do you suggest me to do...?

Comment: @rajivpradeep: There are two answers here which both suggest reasonable courses of action. Jason Williams' answer will fix the issue if administrative rights are the only thing in play. My answer will help you if you are relying on any other Windows XP compatibility shims.

Comment: ok, let me elaborate on what i am trying to do. i have a flash drive divided into two partitions. one is hidden n other is normal , when i plug in the drive the normal part is visible with the application in it. when i run this application in it, it should swap the memory partition now showing the hidden partition, which also contains some demo applications. when i close these applications , the application should again swap the memory. this is what i am trying to do..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Microsoft Application Compatibility Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=24DA89E9-B581-47B0-B45E-492DD6DA2971&displaylang=en), which will tell you exactly which Windows XP compatibility shims are used by your code when you run your application under Windows XP mode.

You simply run your application and disable various shims until your code once again behaves incorrectly. The last shim you disabled is the cause of the incorrect behavior. You can then research the exact consequences of each shim as well as exactly what your code will have to do to fix the bugs it has that force it to run in Windows XP Compatibility Mode.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add an [Application Manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) to your application to request the appropriate security permissions to allow your application to do what it needs to do.

This may cause a UAC prompt to be shown to the user if elevated permissions are needed, but then your code will be allowed to do whatever Windows 7 is currently blocking.

Comment: +1 for suggesting the manifest as the problem, -1 for not pointing at the setting in Visual Studio's project properties that changes this without requiring somebody to write an explicit manifest. Total: 0.

Comment: @rajivpradeep: Project Properties -> Linker -> Manifest File -> UAC Execution Level. Change it to "RequireAdministrator"

Comment: Sorry, the kids decided I needed an early morning and the C++ tag didn't impinge on my brain :-)

Comment: @rajivpradeep: Then you'll need to use MACT (see my answer) to tell exactly why the app fails without Windows XP virtualization. You'll still need Mr. Williams' answer to ask for administrative rights, but you need to address compatibility issues with your code itself. Hopefully it's something simple like the "VersionLie" shim.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the problem exists and know that UAC / etc ... / Manifest on Win7 don't solve your problem and that it's not connected with 32/64 bit issues, try a different approach.

I guess you know what goes wrong with your app on Windows 7. If you're not sure exactly, at least you should know where (in which logical block) your problem is located (e.g IO block, Disk read/write block, Gui, etc.

Now stick to the debugger. Hope your program isn't that big that you can't analyze it and find the source of your problem. You could have your problems because of some functions working not as expected or something like that.

Then, I guess, you could rethink / remanage your code and change it the way it works on both platform. If there is no universal solution, use `#ifdef`s to determine your current platform (the worst case actually, because you would have to have different binary files for different windows versions).